# How can I had Annex and Appendix?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm trying to use both appendices and annexes in a document.

I understand that annexes are not native to latex so I searched the web and found this solution:

```
%% Annex
\newcommand{\annexname}{Annex}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\annex{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\annexname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}}
\makeatother
```

But when I do:

```
\appendix
\include{appendix1}

\annex
\include{annex1}
```

All my annexes end up inside the appendices entry on the TOC.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: It seems like you just copied the definition of `\appendix` from [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls), which shouldn't add anything in the ToC (by default). As such, you must be loading some other package(s) that make "your annexes end up inside the appendices entry in the ToC". Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem?

Comment: It may be as simple as adding `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\annexname}` would suffice...

Comment: I don't know what I did but it is ok on the toc now. However in the pdf outline it's still wrong. MWE comming

Comment: I found the problem while trying to create the MWE. It was a macro on the faculty sty

Comment: Goes to show what a MWE is worth... seeing as this may be too localized (you're using a faculty-specific `.sty`), I'm not sure how many others might benefit from this post. Either completely revamp the question to have some broader relevance, or we should close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that is about a specific choice in a local, private, file.

Comment: I think this question is useful. It just helped me and was also cited in someone else's page: https://cassjohnston.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/latex-add-both-appendices-and-annexes/